# Why does WPF's Dispatcher.Invoke not cause a deadlock when run on the main thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

Consider the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread = button.Dispatcher.Thread
            button.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => button.Content = "1234");
        }
    }
```

Of course, `button_Click` is run on the main thread.

My understanding is that `button.Dispatcher.Thread` is the main thread and the `Invoke()` will get processed only when the thread is not blocked. However, isn't the main thread blocked in this case? I.e. the main thread is waiting for the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` call to complete and `Dispatcher.Invoke()` is waiting for the main thread to free up. So I expect a deadlock here, but it doesn't get deadlocked.

Why?

P.S: I am aware that in this situation I don't need the `Dispatcher.Invoke` and that I can call the `button.Content = "1234"` directly. I am trying to understand why the deadlock DOES NOT happen in this case.

Comment: you don't need that dispatcher; as you say, you are on the ui thread ; just use button.Content = "1234";

Comment: @GCamel Yes, I am aware of that. I am trying to understand, why deadlock does not occur when i do the dispatcher.Invoke(..)

Comment: so in fact, you ask for a problem, not for a solution...? WPF is so good...case seems to be normal : your button_click run and push a delegate into the processing pipe of your app

Comment: The question makes no sense. A deadlock could only occur if at least two threads were involved. Here you have only one - the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens, see Nick's answer. The deadlock WILL occur had the IF condition not been there. EDIT: Just saw the other comments

Comment: @FrankAdams A deadlock wouldn't occur even if that `if` doesn't evaluate to true, and the Dispatcher ends up using its alternative "Slow-Path". That's the path that is taken, even if you invoke it on the same thread, if you use a different priority other than `Send`. There still wouldn't be a deadlock, however, because the main thread is never blocked.

Comment: @FrankAdams You might want to read this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your misunderstanding may be based around the following thought process:

*"Well, Invoke blocks the calling thread until the action is completed. How can it perform the action on the thread if the thread is blocked?"*

If we look inside the source, we see that **the callback is being called not only on the same thread, but directly* inside the Invoke method.** The main thread is not being blocked.

If you look at the dispatcher's [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,4990431309c71f1a) page, you can see the following comment above an `if` statement within the `Invoke` method's implementation, with the callback being called within it:

```
// Fast-Path: if on the same thread, and invoking at Send priority,
// and the cancellation token is not already canceled, then just
// call the callback directly.
if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && priority == DispatcherPriority.Send && CheckAccess())
{
    /* snipped */

    callback();

    /* snipped */
}
```

You're calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` on the main thread, and the method handles that by just calling it instantly.

<sub>*Well, not *directly*, but the entire body of `Invoke(Action)` is just a call to the method that the above code is in.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case, why is it advised to call the CheckAccess() ourselves before calling the Invoke?

Comment: Do you have a source that advises it? That's the first I've heard of that.

Comment: Even if the dispatcher action wasn't called immediately (but queued for later execution) there wouldn't be a deadlock, because there's no other thread than the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens I believe Frank's mindset of his misunderstanding to be something along the lines of "Well, `Invoke` blocks the calling thread until the action is completed. How can it perform the action on the thread if the thread is blocked?" I've added this to my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer perfectly explains the case when priority is `Send`, as asked by OP. But things become even more interesting if we specify any other priority.

```
button.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => button.Content = "1234", DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

The code above does not dead-lock either, even though it cannot call the method directly (it must process messages with higher priorities first).

In this case WPF puts our message in the Dispatcher's queue, and calls the [`Dispatcher.PushFrame()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe) method. It basically spins up a nested message loop for us. The inner `DispatcherFrame` processes queued messages (with higher priorities) until it reaches the one that was placed in the queue by `Invoke()`. After that, the nested frame is stopped, and execution returns from `Invoke()` to the calling method.

Btw, that's also how modal dialogs work. So, it might be easier to understand by looking at it. The call to [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog) method does not return (remains in the call stack) until the dialog is closed. But the application stays responsive because messages are pumped by the inner `DispatcherFrame`.

Source code: [RefereneSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherOperation.cs,4430b5a156164e72).